# How Skype to Skype For Business Communication, is configured?

Tags: lync, skype, skype-for-business-2016

Our office emails hosted on Office-365 / Skype For Business for instant messaging.

Our vendors do not have Skype for business accounts.
What configuration needs to be done on Exchange? We need to connect with them using

> From Skype For Business ==> to Skype Personal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays it is technically possible to add Skype contacts to Skype for Business, but external communication needs to be allowed from Skype for Business admin center **(Office 365)**, first.

> [Let Skype for Business users add Skype contacts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Let-Skype-for-Business-users-add-Skype-contacts-08666236-1894-42ae-8846-e49232bbc460)
>
> 1. Sign in with your Office 365 admin account at https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home.
> 2. In the Office 365 admin center, go to **Admin Centers** > **Skype for Business**.
> 3. In the **Skype for Business admin center**, choose **organization** > **external communications**.
> 4. Choose **Let people use Skype for Business to communicate with Skype users outside your organization**.
> 5. WAIT UP TO 24 HOURS TO TEST

This is a shortened version. The original documentation linked goes through all the settings.

All these settings are company-wide i.e. affecting the whole Office 365 tenant.

If you have **Skype for Business Server** 2015, you'd need to [Deploy Skype Connectivity](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn705313.aspx).

> Skype for Business Server 2015 uses the federation access architecture
>   to support connectivity with Skype. This connectivity enables your
>   Skype for Business Server users to add Skype. Skype clients can also
>   add Skype for Business users to their contact list. Based on policies
>   administratively set in Skype for Business Server users will be able
>   to communicate using instant messaging, see each other’s presence, and
>   initiate audio and video calls.

Comment: +1, will accept in 24 hrs :-)